# In AngularJS, how do I go about linking an image to an url?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working on an AngularJS application and I would like to have an image which, if clicked, redirects to an URL.

I already am able to do that but with text. This is what my code looks like:

#### JS:

```
myLink:
{
LinkText: "Click here for the pdf:",
LinkHRef: "/documents/pdfs/Final.pdf"
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<div class="basic-page__link" ng-if="section.myLink">
 <a ng-if="section.myLink.sectionLinkNewTab !== false" target="_blank" 
ng-href="{{ section.myLink.LinkHref }}">{{ 
section.myLink.LinkText }}</a>
<a ng-if="section.myLink.sectionLinkNewTab === false" ng-href="
{{section.myLink.LinkHref }}">
{{section.myLink.LinkText }}</a>
</div>
```

This works for me whenever I want to have clickable text, but how would I implement a clickable image?

Thank you!

Comment: I see `LinkHref ` and `LinkHRef` maybe you have a typo?

Comment: Also have you tried wrapping a link around the image? like `<a ng-if="section.myLink.sectionLinkNewTab === false" ng-href="
{{section.myLink.LinkHref }}"> <img src='my/source'/> </a>`

Comment: Just put the image anywhere inside the <a> tags

Answer (score 0):

ng-src is the directive to use i believe. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Answer (score 0):

Just use image tag `<img>` to show a image. And to make this image clickable there are various options.
You can include in inside you anchor tag `<a>`

Something like this

```
<a target="_blank" ng-href="{{ section.myLink.LinkHref }}">
<img data-ng-src="{{icon.source}}" alt="{{section.myLink.LinkText}}"/>
</a>
```